# Scraping number of likes and comments from an Instagram post via Google Sheet IMPORTXML

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, scrape

I am a noob at importXML. The XPath to the number of likes is

`//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/section[2]/div/a/span`

So the formula for the scraping the number of likes from this post: https://www.instagram.com/p/BZLli5ll6yz/ should be:

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.instagram.com/p/BZLli5ll6yz/", "//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/section[2]/div/a/span")`

Right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the xpath the "react-root" is in a subclass: 'react-root'. This keeps it contained within the second argument.